# SwiftUI | Stop TextField from moving up with keyboard automatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Since iOS14 I have found that all my `TextField`s are moving up automatically once the keyboard appears.

I haven't found a way to stop this, have I missed something?

Here is a simple Demo+Code:

*Demo:*

[image]

*Code:*

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var textInput: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Test", text: $textInput)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is possible solution for your scenario. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        TextField("Test", text: $textInput)
        Spacer()
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
}
```