# How do you prevent SwiftUI from autoresizing view when keyboard appears

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, textfield, autoresize

I have a TextField in my iOS app, and it is positioned such that I don't want it to move when the keyboard appears. However, the view is autoresizing when the keyboard appears. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type", text: self.$text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292661/12299030?

Comment: Yes -- sorry I didn't come across this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a modifier to tell a certain view to ignore specific or all iOS safe areas. Apply the following `.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)` to the parent view, and it will not resize when the keyboard is open.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had a modal on a modal (I presented a share sheet and the share sheet presented Messages) and my underlying view was getting squished. Putting this on there fixed it!