# Keyboard not overlaying the view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

So i want my keyboard to overlay the view so that the view stays and not going upwards. i did several variations such as adding it in my loginstuff, or adding in it navigationView. it doesn't work at all

Here's my code

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var userData = UserData()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment:.top) {
                Color.pink.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "graduationcap.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.top,30)
                    Text("Study +")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Spacer()
                    //Mark : The login Thinggy
                    LoginStuffs()
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .navigationTitle("Login")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Login Stuff

```
struct LoginStuffs: View {
    @State var username:String = ""
    @State var password:String = ""
    @State var isShow:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
       Vstack{
Textfield()
Securefield()
Securefield()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width:UIScreen.width,height:UIScreen.height/1.5)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(15, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
        //.ignoresSafeArea(edges: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bottom/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

Seems like there's a problem within my codes in which I did not know (probably due to not learn it properly). please do help, thank you for your attention
[image: The Problem]

Comment: i already tried to add
```.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)```
into the view ,didn't work

Comment: add  `LoginStuffs()`

Comment: i did, i tried the variations, didnt work

Comment: I meant add the code for  `LoginStuffs()`.. :)

Comment: owww, okkk. i see

Comment: Please add reproducible  code !

Comment: Okay. here you go

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292661/12299030?

Comment: sortish, if i use the same code from the example, yes. but when I tried to applied it into my codes, nope

Answer (score 0):

use on your NavigationView

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom))
```

Comment: if the NavigationView is nested in an other view add to that one, you must add it to the top level view

Comment: i did put it in the top level (I think)

Comment: i did not, you are using LoginView from an other view, try adding it to LoginView if does not work add it to the view containing LoginView

Comment: something like this right ```struct Controller: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}```

still not working