# How to stop View content from moving up when we open keyboard?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, swift-keyboard

I want the view content not moves up when I open the keyboard  I have more content in the view so it push the top content out of the screen and I want it unchanged when the keyboard is open or closed.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292534/swiftui-stop-textfield-from-moving-up-with-keyboard-automatically/64292661#64292661) but its not working in my case on small screen the content goes out of screen . Its only works if we have less content inside view .

**My Code**

```
struct ContentView34: View {
    @State var phoneNumber = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Image("homeIcon")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:Constants.width*0.6,height: Constants.width*0.5)
                    .padding()
                Text("Enter your phone number")
                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                Text("Sign in with Apple id or Gmail")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 15))
                    .font(.caption)
                    .padding(.top,0.2)
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(Color("blue"))
                        .frame(width: 90,height:50)
                    Text("Mobile")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.caption2)
                        .padding(.horizontal,10)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 90,height:70,alignment: .topLeading)
                    HStack{
                        Group{
                            Image("flag")
                            Text("+44")
                                .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 15))
                            Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .frame(width: 10, height: 6)
                                .padding(0)
                        }
                        Divider()
                            .frame(width:2 ,height: 25)
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                        TextField("Enter phone number", text: $phoneNumber)
                            .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 15))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("dayNightText"))
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(width: Constants.width*0.9,height: 50)
                    .padding(.leading)
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
                ZStack{
                    VStack{
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Sign in with Apple")
                                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 14))
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .frame(width: Constants.width * 0.6, height: 45)
                            .foregroundColor( .white)
                            .background(Color.black)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .overlay(
                                Image("apple")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .renderingMode(.template)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width:25,height:25)
                                    .frame(width: 50,height:45,alignment: .leading)
                            )
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        Button {
                            
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Sign in with Google")
                                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 14))
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .frame(width: 60,height:45)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color("blue"))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .overlay(
                                Image("google")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    .frame(width:25,height:25)
                                    .frame(width: 50,height:45,alignment: .leading)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    Text("Testing1")
                    Text("Testing1")
                    Text("Testing1")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
            }
             .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView34_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView34()
    }
}
```

**When keyboard is closed**

[image]

**When keyboard is open the image top cuts**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a `ScrollView`? The OS tries to do the right thing, and keep the view that has focus where it can be seen when the keyboard appears. The other thing you can try is set a listener on the keyboard, and shrink your image when the keyboard appears so you can still see everything, but remember, this will be different for different devices. You could also try `ViewThatFits`, and just provide an alternate view to show. But, you only have so much room.

Comment: yeah I tried with scrollView and its working as expected but my employer wants me to do it without Scrollview and I have one other view where scrollView will not work

Comment: Well, then you have option 2 above.